# Build a magnet field sensor like a Hall sensor large scale

Tags: sensor, proximity-sensor

I want to build a sensor that can see changes in the magnetic field, like a hall sensor but larger, I want to be able to see the changes in the magnet field around high power tension lines and around cell towers, If there is a magnetic disturbance I want to see it.

I need to know how to build a Hall effect sensor big enough to do that. What can I use for the HAll Element.

Bigger question is the HAll Effect Sensor the best thing to use for this?

Comment: What you should do instead is **amplify** the signal from your Hall effect sensor. (Many hall effect sensors already come with internal amplifiers). - Either way, I doubt you will get any meaningful reading. It would probably work better as a true random number generator.

Comment: A much more dramatic effect is to walk under high power lines with a fluorescent tube light bulb held up in the air. This works on the same principle (being excited by the magnetic field)...

Comment: Ok so maybe I didn’t word it right, I want to see magnetfield disturbances for a 1oo yard radius or more.

Comment: @RonBeyer I believe that's the electric field, not magnetic.

Answer (score 2):

Some math here.

Assume the power line carries 100,000 volts at 10,000 amps, or one GigaWatt.
This will be 3-phase in reality, with some of the fields partially cancelling because of moderate distances between the 3 phases.

We will assume the 10,000 amps is 50 meters up and in just ONE WIRE.

At ground level, you have a 1meter by 1meter loop. What voltage is induced into that loop?

Vinduce = [MU0 * MUr * Area * dI/dT ] / (2*pi * Distance)

Vinduce = 2e-7 * Area/Distance * dI /dT

Vinduce = 2e-7 * 1metersquare/50 meters * [10,000amps * 377] assuming pure sin

Vinduce = 2e-7 * 0.02 * 3.77e+6

Vinduce ~~ 16 * e-7 e-2 e+6 = 16e-3 = 16 milliVolts.

If you wind 100 turns, you will have 1.6 volts, and can feed that into any MCU ADC, as long as one end of the 100-turn loop is biased near VDD/2.

Answer (score 2):

Hall sensors are fine for unchanging fields, "DC magnetism," but they're not very sensitive (they're designed for 10gauss and above.)

For weaker magnetic disturbances you'll want an AC-field receiver: a large coil with an amplifier.  There are two methods:  1) wind a wide hoop-coil, using a pound or two of enamel-coated small-gauge "magnet wire" (many turns.)   Or, 2) build or buy a very long iron core (laminated iron, or better, [extremely large ferrite rods](http://www.stormwise.com/page26.htm),) then wind a pound or two of fine wire onto it.   Then, amplify the coil's signals using a standard audio amp, perhaps a low-noise microphone preamplifier.  Use headphones to directly listen to the signals, or view/record signals with an oscilloscope or PC soundcard.

[image]

Fortunately lots of people are already building such projects.  The magnetic signals aren't a part of normal EM broadcasts, instead they're called "VLF" for Very Low Freq.   A ferrite-core coil (or a wide loop-coil) is actually an antenna for magnetic field signals.  So, google up some [ferrite rod VLF](https://www.google.com/search?q=vlf%20%22ferrite%20rod%22&num=100&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X) antennas and projects.

- http://www.vlf.it/inductor/inductor.htm, also http://www.vlf.it/
- http://digilander.libero.it/bubblegate/ecircuit1.html#SENSITIVE
- http://www.sarmento.eng.br/Loop_Ferrite_Rod_Antenna.htm

[image]

---

On the other hand, if you want to detect the large fields near overhead AC power lines, only a small coil is needed.  These inexpensive ["telephone pickup" coils](https://www.allelectronics.com/item/tpx-1/telephone-pick-up/1.html) can connect to any 3.5mm microphone input on a [mini audio amplifier.](https://www.google.com/search?q=2771008+amplifier&num=100&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X)  Wave the coil around in an office, and you'll detect all sorts of strong magnetic signals.

---

More, magnetic detectors for magnetic storms, solar CMEs, VLF Schumann signals, etc.

- [Magnetometer projects](http://www.backyardastronomy.net/compass-fluxgate-magnetometer-projects/) at backyard astronomy
- [DIY automated magnetometer](http://web.archive.org/web/20000302142300/http://www.sciam.com/2000/0300issue/0300amsci.html), also [simpler vers.](https://makezine.com/2017/11/29/april-wilkersons-shop-gift-guide/) "The Amateur Scientist"
- [PVC magnetometer](http://avtanski.net/projects/magnetometer/index.html) detects solar storms
- [Detect UFOs](https://borderlandsciences.org/project/bio-icomm/lg.lawrence/Magnetometers_for_Investigating_UFOs.html) with various backyard magnetometers
- [popular FGM-3 fluxgate head](https://www.google.com/search?q=fgm+fluxgate&num=100&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X) is still for sale fgsensors.com
- [VLF antenna](http://www.vlf.it/romero3/ics101.html), induction coil and amplifier  1/2Hz to 200Hz
- [Fluxgate Magnetometer construction](https://www.google.com/search?q=diy+fluxgate&num=100&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X)
- [DIY proton magnetometers,](https://www.google.com/search?q=diy%20proton%20magnetometer&num=100&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X) ultra hyper-sensitive

---

Comment: Thanks for the input I thought I new what I wanted now I am more confused than ever, when an object like a motor or a large magnet comes near the sensor it should see the change in the magnetfield around the sensor and when that happens I want to see it either on a multimeter or a alarm of some kind so please tell me lol what type of sensor do I want?

Comment: @Jimwilder A hall sensor detects nearby magnets, but for more distant magnets, or for testing Earth's magnetic field direction, you'd need something more sensitive: a "Fluxgate" magnetometer module.   Or, to ignore magnets but detect the 60Hz AC leakage-fields from a power line or a motor, use the above VLF coil method, since its far less expensive than other sensors.  Quick test for 60Hz magnetism: use a DMM to read AC volts on a pickup-coil, then hold it near an operating motor. Also, search: fluxgate arduino

Comment: Finally I think I’m getting somewhere, so I did search that and it sounds exactly what I want to do, so lets say there was external magnetic source or if something was to influence the the earths magnetic field that would alarm what kind of distance would that work that work for to see an alarm ?

Comment: @Jimwilder I added more links above. Inexpensive DIY laser mirror-compass, detects magnetic storms, just rig a photosensor to trigger alarm.  For the really hypersensitive detectors, search DIY proton magnetometers, also DIY Overhauser magnetometers.  Much better: potassium atomic-clock magnetometers for your large hexacopter, fly the countryside and desert, locate huge iron meteorites?! http://www.gemsys.ca/uav-magnetometers/